# Why can't MRO be created when a subclass inherits from super class and another class which inherits from same super class?

Tags: python, inheritance

In a python course they discuss classes and MRO. The following example fails

```py
class A:
    def info(self):
        print('Class A')

class B(A):
    def info(self):
        print('Class B')

class C(A):
    def info(self):
        print('Class C')

class D(A, C):
    pass

D().info()
```

with the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
    class D(A, C):
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases A, C
```

But the MRO is described to follow this path:

1. Check for `info` in `D` (since we call `info` on `D`)
2. if not, check for `info` in the super-classes, left to right

Why doesn't it just use the `info` from `A`? Switching `A` to `B` works fine

```py
class D(B,C):
   pass

D.info() # "Class B"
```